# Mongoose use $and to apply same attribute two filters

Tags: mongoose, filter

I have a status attribute and I want to apply a date filter **only if status is pending**, for the other status  a date filter is not required.

1. return only the status added to "$in".
2. if status is pending apply a date filter (date is less than current time).

I do like this, but it is not working fine.

```
   filter = { $and: [ { 
                'package' : {$in: ids}, 
                'status':  {$in: ['pending', 'accepted',  'charged', 'captured']},
                date  
                },
                {
                    $and:[
                        {status : 'pending', date:{$lt:current_time}},
                    ]
                }
            ]
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- use `$or` instead of `$and`, because it would satisfy one of condition
- remove `pending` status from `$in` condition
- `$and` to wrap `package` condition and `$or` conditions

```
filter = {
  $and: [
    { package: { $in: ids } },
    {
      $or: [
        { status: { $in: ["accepted", "charged", "captured"] } },
        {
          status: "pending",
          date: { $lt: current_time }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nkzvaQc_aMk)